# Java: Find installation path from the registry

Tags: java, registry

Im going to create a launcher for a mod (for C&C Generals: Zero Hour), and i am implementing an updater within the launcher.
The problem is, how to find the installation path of that game? just by looking at the registry?

Comment: better ask the user to select installation folder and check for the presence of the C&C game structure there

Comment: Some people are way so dumb to find the installation directory of the game. so i am implementing this thing so it would be easier for them to install and play the mod.
if there is no signs of installation in the registry, then they must input the installation directory manually.

Comment: I can agree on end users' dumbness, still we're considering an user that actually knows how to install a module, so the assumption he/she can locate the installation folder of a game is kinda good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest offering the default installation folder and checking that the game is actually there, if not tell the user to set himself the path.

Anyway, maybe this page can help you:

[How to Access Windows Registry in Java?](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-access-windows-registry-in-java/152)